Question related to work done by spring
I was trying this question: A block of mass 250g is kept on a vertical spring of spring constant 100N/m fixed from below. The spring is now compressed to have a length 10cm shorter than its natural length and the system is released from this position how high does the block rise? take g=10m/s
So, the equation in solution is kx^2/2 = mgh    |   (x=10cm)
My question is why is there not a k(h-x)^2/2 added on the right hand side because its the work done by spring after the block crosses the natural length.
so the equation would look like this: kx^2/2 = mgh + k(h-x)^2

That's because the block is lying freely over the spring and not attached to it.
So , once the spring has attained it's natural length , it won't elongate further as it has reached its own equilibrium and further the block would be in air converting the kinetic energy into its potential energy.

If you do these kinds of problems often enough, you get used to the fact that the results with and without gravity are all pretty much the same.
